# ios - AVPlayer - Playback volume very low

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

When playing a local .mp3 recording with AVPlayer, the volume is very low (because of the original recording is of low quality) and the users cannot hear it even with `AVPlayer.volume = 1.0` (100%).

How can I make the audio play louder, add some more gain to the volume so that sounds more like 150-200%? (Setting volume to `2.0` doesn't help).

**UPDATE:** I actually think it will require some kind of preprocessing the audio (to add additional 'gain'), I just don't know what is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `AVPlayer.volume` is in aspect to the current system volume , you can't override it